# How do i add the dice numbers together for highscore + fail

Tags: javascript, html

I have a roll the dice game I have to make for school, I have come far.. the game is working but my problem is that I have to make a highscore system and restrict 6,7,8,9 (if the total is any of those depends on what the player is choosing) it fails the game and you start over.

I just wanna make a highscore and that fail part for my project.

I have done this so far:

```js
let images = ["dice1.png",
"dice2.png",
"dice3.png",
"dice4.png",
"dice5.png",
"dice6.png"];
let dice = document.querySelectorAll("img");

function roll(){
    dice.forEach(function(die){
        die.classList.add("shake");
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        dice.forEach(function(die){
            die.classList.remove("shake");
    });
    let dieOneValue = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)
    ;
    let dieTwoValue = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)
    ;
    console.log(dieOneValue,dieTwoValue);
    document.querySelector("#die-1").setAttribute
    ("src", images[dieOneValue]);
    document.querySelector("#die-2").setAttribute
    ("src", images[dieTwoValue]);
    document.querySelector("#total").innerHTML = 
    "Du rullade " + ( (dieOneValue +1) + (dieTwoValue + 1 ) )
},
1000
);
}
```

And this is the part they only can choose a number or els they get a error message.

```js
var numb=document.forms['myform']['num'];
var error=document.getElementById('error');

function validation()
{
    if(numb.value=='')
    {
        error.innerHTML="Bara nummer funkar";
        error.style.display="block";
        return false;
    }
    
    if(numb.value>9)
    {
        error.innerHTML="Bara nummer 6,7,8,9 funkar";
        error.style.display="block";
        return false;
    }
    if (numb.value<6)
    {
        error.innerHTML="Bara nummer 6,7,8,9 funkar";
        error.style.display="block";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your actual question is or where you're getting stuck. Can you specify what part needs attention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need an input field to ask your player for a "fail" number.

```
<input id="fail-number" type="number" min="6" max="9">
```

At that point you will probably need a button to start the game. And the roll dice button shouldn't be visible.

Your EventListener on the start-game button, should only fire, if the number input has a value.

```
startGame.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(failNumber){
    //toggle class on startGame which makes the button invisible
    //toggle class on rollDice which makes the button visible
    //toggle class on number-input which makes the input invisible
    //roll dice or let the user press rollDice button
  };
});
```

Now you only need to check after every dice roll if the summed dice numbers are like your failNumber.

```
if(diceSum == failNumber){
  //save current score as highscore
  //set current score to 0
  //toggle class on rollDice which makes button invisible
  //toggle class on startGame which makes button visible
  //toggle class on number-input which makes input visible
} else {
  //add diceSum to current score
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad if I made it unclear etc. I'm making a website and not that usual roll the dice game u might see on google player vs computer and u write how many times it should roll and then u see who wins.

This is how my page looks atm.
[website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KirBe.png)

And I wanna make a code that deletes the possibility of picking anything other then 6,7,8 or 9 as a "fail" number. If you land on the chosen number you have lost the game, counts your highscore and make it not possible to continue if you dont restart.

Thanks so much in advance!
ps: My brain is fried on this part.

Comment: Please don't answer your own question with additional information. Instead you should edit your original question. I edited my last answer and hope to get you on the right track with this one.

Comment: Further information regarding the question should be added via edits not an answer